# Generalization of tangents to circle theorem.

Tags: geometry, spheres, solid-geometry

There is this commonly known and easy to prove theorem that if you have a circle $O$ and two lines that are tangent to $O$ (one of them is tangent at some point $A$ and the other one is tangent at some $B$) and they meet at point $P$ outside of the circle then $|PA| = |PB|$. I was wondering if there is some generalization (or similar theorem) of this theorem to $3$ dimensions, so a sphere and three planes tangent to it and having something in common. Have you heard about anything like that?

Comment: The circle result can be stated simply: *The tangent segments to a circle from an external point are congruent.* This statement is true as-is if you replace "circle" with "sphere". In the case of a circle, there are two tangent segments; in the case of a sphere, there are infinitely many segments, and together they form a cone. If we restrict our attention to three (or more!) tangent planes that meet at a common point, $P$, we can say that the segments from $P$ to each plane's point of tangency have the same length. (Notice that those planes would all be tangent to $P$'s tangent cone.)

Answer (score 1):

For any $2$ points on the sphere $S^2$, there exists a greater circle that goes through both of them. If two of the tangent lines intersect, they lie on the defining plane for this greater circle, and hence the $2$ dimensional version of the theorem applies.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. In fact, I meant something else. There is a sphere and 3 different planes tangent to this sphere having some common point $P$. Is there anything that we can say about areas or volumes of some parts of these planes like we said about equal lengths of segments?